# NLog filter based on time of the day

Tags: nlog

I am trying to use NLog [conditions](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Conditions) to filter messages that are not generated at certain time

the following is my sample

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="InfoMail" >
  <when condition="starts-with('${date:format=hh}', '01')" action="Ignore"/>
</logger>
```

However, Nlog seemed not able to pick up '${date:format=hh}' and I still receive email even the messages are generated at one o'clock.
Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `when` conditions should be put inside a `filters` element as show in [Conditions - Examples](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Conditions) and specified in the [NLog.xsd](http://nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd) (the syntax on the [When filter](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/When_filter) page is wrong)

So the correct usage is:

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Console" >
  <filters>
    <when condition="starts-with('${date:format=hh}', '01')" action="Ignore"/>
  </filters>
</logger>
```

Comment: awsome! I don't know how I missed the "filter" part. Thanks a lot.